# How can I shorten my while loop without having to search through number (in string format) 1-10?

Tags: java, string

```
    //Input Number
    System.out.print("Enter a number from 1-10: ");
    words = input.next();

    //Processing String
    if(!words.equals(FLAG)){
        while(!words.equals("1") && !words.equals("2") && !words.equals("3") &&
            !words.equals("4") && !words.equals("5") && !words.equals("6") &&
            !words.equals("7") && !words.equals("8") && !words.equals("9") &&
            !words.equals("10")){
            System.out.print("Please enter a number in integer form from 1-10: ");
            words = input.next(); 
        }
    }
    //Close Scanner
    input.close();

    //String to Integer
    num = Integer.parseInt(words);

    //Output Number
    if(num >=1 || num <=10){
        System.out.println("\nYour number is: " + num);
    }
```

How could i change the while loop? What if the number range was from 1-100? IS there any way to shorten the processing string segment? The program needs to be able to handle string and integers.

Comment: Please explain exactly what your loop is suppose to do. I think I have an idea what it should do, but I want you to explain it; not only for clarity but because it will also help you understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: parse it first, if it doesn't parse its not a number. If it does parse check between minimum and maximums - done

Comment: This will ask the user for a number between 1-10. If the user inputs a String, then the program will loop until a Integer is entered. Right now it is being inputed as string and is being converted to an integer. It will then display the number that the user entered.

Answer (score 6):

Parse it to an `Integer`

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(words);
```

and loop :

```
while( !(number > 0 && number <= 10) ){ // loop the loop }
```

*N.B: Because you will be using parseInt(), you will need to learn to use try-catch blocks. Do look it up*.

Answer (score 2):

You can also directly use `nextInt()` method of the Scanner class for an input of Integer data type.

So you can do,

```
num = input.nextInt();
```

and then directly,

```
//Output Number
if(num >=1 || num <=10){
    System.out.println("\nYour number is: " + num);
}
```

Comment: You can also validate this to ensure your correct input, see here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm

Answer (score 1):

Make a min int and a max int.

```
int min =1;
int max =10; // change to 100 for if you wanted it bigger
```

Then when you get their value simply parse it(Parse turns it into an Interger)

```
int value= Integer.parseInt(words);
```

The final while loop would look like this:

```
while( !(number > min && number <= max) ){
   //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to 'shorten' it would be to `parse` it before the while loop. You should be throwing `NumberFormatException` and putting your code in a `try`/`catch` block if you're going to be parsing strings to ints.

```
public void f() throws NumberFormatException{
    try{
        // other code

        num = Integer.parseInt(words);

        while( !(num>0 && num<=10) ){
            // magic
        }

        // other code
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        // handle it!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `do` `while` loop so that you don't have to ask the user for input twice, just let the loop do the work for you.

```
int number;
final int MIN = 0;
final int MAX = 100;

do
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a number in integer form from 1-10: ");
    words = input.next(); 

    number = Integer.parseInt(words);

}while(!(number > MIN && number <= MAX));
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the input into an Integer before check validation.

But do remember to handle exception properly.

```
int number;

while(true){
    try{
        number = Integer.parseInt(words);
        if(number <= 10 && number >= 1) break;
        else
            System.out.print("Your number is out of range (1, 10):");
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.print("Please input valid number from 1 to 10:");
    }

    words = input.next();
}

System.out.println("Your number is " + number);
```